# Error in php.ini file after updating for Xdebug

Tags: php, xdebug

I am using webmatirx to build a website using PHP. I wanted to debug the code.I followed the steps mentioned in the link - http://ruslany.net/2011/02/how-to-enable-xdebug-in-webmatrix/

My php.ini file looks like - 
[image]

In the error message the line number mentioned is thezend_extension line. Please let me now how can I resolve this.
The error message I receive is - 
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is likely caused by your zend_extension declaration. If you have spaces or special characters you should wrap the string in quotes